# Calling the rest api in php

Tags: php, rest, curl, flipkart-api

Hi Good evening currently working on flipkart / snapdeal rest api in which  we have to curl the data . In command prompt its working fine  and give me desired output . But now i want to call that in code and unable to do that . Kindly help me out for that . Api contain the token and token id . here my command which is working fine.

```
curl -H "Fk-Affiliate-Id:abhishekbh" -H "Fk-Affiliate-Token:2dacb05681b8481eb65201283dac2630" "https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/feeds/abhishebh/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1489539219049&sig=ad5ef1af7f41d68d9f8f1c1ae85e20b6"
```

Comment: Have a look at the [PHP cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), you'll be able to build an equivalent for your cmd line in PHP.

Comment: ya i check that but i am confused in that

Comment: Based on your tags, I'm assuming you want PHP code?  Are you wanting to use any specific library?  You might also try using Guzzle http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/  If you make an attempt at it, you can post that code back here, and it will be better for us to help you debug rather than write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the php code to send request using curl.

```
$s = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/feeds/abhishekbh/category/7jv.json?expiresAt=1489539219049&sig=ad5ef1af7f41d68d9f8f1c1ae85e20b6'); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Fk-Affiliate-Id:abhishekbh', 'Fk-Affiliate-Token:2dacb05681b8481eb65291283dac2630')); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
$result = curl_exec($s);

echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Don't mention the actual secret credentials (affiliate-id,affiliate-token) in the forums. Everyone can see the actual output then.

Comment: ok sir its does not give any error but does not show any json

Comment: Open the http://phpfiddle.org/ and in code-pace run the above code. you can see the output in json format. If that works, it means it is working. http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/colavita-fusilli-pasta/p/itmea7z22ruvxtga?pid=PSAEA7Z2YGAFGGYW&affid=abhishekbh this is product url i got in the response.

Comment: ya its working but why its not working on local server

Comment: http://sabkideal.com/snap/curl.php ya its working but not coming in proper json view

Comment: Set CURLOPT_HEADER as false like `curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);` this. I have set as true in the answer i posted. When this param is set as true, you will get the output header also in the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138039/discussion-between-siddiq-and-indian-thinking).